# Cassandra DB - No active nodes?

Tags: database, cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra and I'm trying to make a basic Cassandra server but I am having difficulties. Through some sheer miracle, I've managed to create a keyspace and some tables. However, whenever I try interacting with the tables, I get the following error:

"Unable to execute CQL script on 'Localhost': not enough replicas available for query at consistency ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)))"

The message lead me to believe I have no active nodes, but I have cassandra.bat (I'm on win10) running in the background and that has allowed me to connect and create keyspaces and tables.

Moreover, when I try doing anything with nodetool, it processes indefinitely (or takes very long time, I'm too impatient to find out but I guessed the former due to my previous assumption).

My keyspace is NetworkTopologyStrategy with 1 datacenter of a replication factor 3 and durable write enabled.

Anybody has any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First, you're specified replication factor equal to 3, although you have only one node.  Second - you need to check what datacenter name you did specify in the `NetworkTopologyStrategy` - you can find it if you execute `nodetool status`. After that make changes into existing keyspace using command:

```
ALTER  KEYSPACE keyspace_name 
   WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter_name' : 1};
```

P.S. I recommend to watch DS201/210/220 courses on the [DataStax Academy](http://academy.datastax.com/) - this will give you a good overview of Cassandra, base operations, and data modelling.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Didn't know they had one. However, upon watching the videos I realized I made a huge mistake. I have a table whose function is only to be sorted by a certain column, and I want to be able to pull top x elements of that table. However, I need to provide a partition key (I think) but that will partition my entire table in a very inefficient way. All of my columns vary drastically from one another so I don't know what to partition by. How do I do this in Cassandra, to have a table that is sorted by a single column? Imagine a table of people and I want to sort them by weight.

Comment: Basically - yes, you need to have different tables if you want to sort by different columns. But it really depends on the task, and in many cases materialized views can help with automatically propagate changes. Regarding the partition key - it should be selected such way so it will provide more or less uniform data distribution in the cluster - don't create big partitions, etc. But I believe that this will be covered in DS220 courses. DataStax Enterprise (DSE) also includes DSE Search component that allows to index on many/all columns, so you can get sort on them on single table